# Depuis quand a-t-on l'emploi du terme « islamophobie » et peut-on présenter des sources l'attestant ?

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, origine-ou-raison, religion

L'*islamophobie* (n.f.) est un(e) :

- Attitude négative ou hostilité manifestée à l'égard des musulmans, de
  leurs pratiques religieuses ou de leur culture. ([GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8354162))
- Hostilité envers l'islam, les musulmans. ([Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/islamophobie/186470?q=islamophobie#10927814))
- Ensemble de jugements négatifs à l’encontre de l'islam, voire des
  personnes de confession musulmane. ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/islamophobie))
- Une hostilité de principe à l'égard de l'Islam et des musulmans
  [...]. (DHLF)
- [etc.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamophobie#D%C3%A9finition_et_sens)

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* indique que l'adjectif (*islamophobe*) et le nom seraient « apparus dans les années 1980 » (coïncidant  avec la [théorie](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamophobie#Origines_et_usages) des mollahs iraniens établissant son origine à 1979). Le nom est absent du TLF et du dictionnaire de l'Académie ; le Wiktionnaire indique 1910 et son article n'est pas relié à l'[article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamophobie#D%C3%A9finition_et_sens) de Wikipédia sur le sujet (contrairement à [antisémitisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antis%C3%A9mitisme), [antiracisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiracisme), [antifascisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antifascisme) etc.).

---

À quand remonte le terme *islamophobie* en langue française (1910 ou 1980) et peut-on identifier des sources attestées de son emploi ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit sans contredit au plus tard de **1910** et l'origine du terme a fait l'objet d'une révision ayant induit en erreur bon nombre de gens sous prétexte que l'*islamophobie* ne signifiait pas *racisme anti-musulman* etc. Mais depuis quand un terme n'existe pas parce qu'il aurait eu un sens différent — et rien n'est moins certain dans au moins un des extraits suivants — que celui qu'on voudrait bien lui accoler pour satisfaire ses prétentions ?

---

[image]

> *L'Islamophobie.* — Il y a toujours eu, et il y a encore, un préjugé contre l'Islam répandu chez les peuples de civilisation occidentale et
>   chrétienne.
>
> Pour d'aucuns, le musulman est l'ennemi naturel et irréconciliable du
>   chrétien et de l'Européen, l'islamisme est la négation de la
>   civilisation, et la barbarie, la mauvaise foi et la cruauté sont tout
>   ce qu'on peut attendre de mieux des mahométans.

[*La Politique musulmane dans l'Afrique occidentale française*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6152175h/f152.item.r) (1910), par Alain Quellien à la p. 10.

---

[image]

> Quoi qu'en disent ceux pour qui l'islamophobie est un principe
>   d'administration indigène, la France n'a rien de plus à craindre des
>   Musulmans en Afrique occidentale que des non-Musulmans. Les uns et les
>   autres nous considèrent comme des maîtres parfois gênants, parfois
>   utiles, généralement bienveillants, et nous subissent avec plus ou
>   moins de facilité selon la diversité de leurs caractères ou de leurs
>   intérêts. Ceux d'entre eux qui désireraient le plus ardemment nous
>   voir partir du pays — et il s'en trouve certainement — le désirent,
>   non pas parce que nous ne sommes pas de leur foi, mais simplement
>   parce que nous ne sommes ni de leur race, ni de leur mentalité, ni de
>   leur sol, parce que nous sommes l'étranger.
>
> Les Noirs surtout ne sont ni des mystiques ni des philosophes
>   spéculatifs ce sont des matérialistes superstitieux, qui n'adoptent
>   telle ou telle religion que parce qu'ils sont persuadés que les
>   pratiques de cette religion détourneront d'eux des maux tangibles,
>   tels que la maladie ou la mort, ou que l'abstention de ces pratiques
>   amènera sur eux les mêmes maux. Quant à la doctrine, elle ne passe
>   qu'au second plan, et il est douteux qu'on puisse rencontrer chez eux
>   beaucoup de fidèles disposés à subir le martyre plutôt que de renier
>   leur foi.
>
> L'islamophobie n'a donc pas de raison d'être dans l'Afrique
>   occidentale, où l'islamophilie, dans le sens d'une préférence accordée
>   aux Musulmans, créerait d'autre part un sentiment de méfiance parmi
>   les populations non-musulmanes, qui se trouvent être les plus
>   nombreuses. L'intérêt de la domination européenne, comme aussi
>   l'intérêt bien entendu des indigènes, nous fait donc un devoir de
>   désirer le maintien du statu quo et de garder une neutralité absolue
>   vis-à-vis de tous les cultes.

[*L'état actuel de l'islam dans l'Afrique occidentale française, article paru dans La revue du monde musulman*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k103806r/f56.item.r) (1910) ds. Revue du monde musulman, par Maurice Delafosse à la p. 53.

Answer (score 3):

Complément à la excellente réponse :

Voici un [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=islamophobie%2Cislamophobe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cislamophobie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cislamophobe%3B%2Cc0) pertinent montrant justement que les premières apparences du mot sont attestées durant les années de 1910s.

Deux articles intéressants portant sur l'histoire du mot :

https://islamophobie.hypotheses.org/193

https://www.atlantico.fr/decryptage/3315241/petite-histoire-du-terme-islamophobie-et-de-son-utilisation-a-des-fins-politiques

NB Le n-gram montre aussi que le terme était marginal avant 1998. –
(merci @Mathieu Bouville pour le remarque)

Comment: Le n-gram montre aussi que le terme était marginal avant 1998.